# querying by a part of the ObjectID in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b9f472a20f7a27d8ae2ab48"),

db.getCollection('col_cost').find({_id:ObjectId("5b9f472a20f7a27d8ae2ab48")})
```

how can I find this document by calling "e2ab48"?

Mongodb version 3.4.2   and  my collection https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c76174b321e545ba82fc2dd785ff3513 
I want to call CostId. Can I find this cost with a 6-digit string?

Comment: Can you share your collection at jsoneditor online

Comment: which Mongo version are you using?

Comment: I edited my question @MaheshBhatnagar

Comment: @tomslabbaert ı added

Answer (score 0):

Use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

```
db.getCollection('col_cost').find({ $where: "this._id.str.match(/.*e2ab48/)" })
```

Comment: Eyvallah. Thank you